# howdy is not working on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: lock-screen, authentication, 23.04

I recently upgraded my system to Ubuntu 23.04. However, Howdy is not functioning properly on the lock screen or any other authentication process.
I attempted to reinstall it, but it did not solve the problem. On the other hand, I can still add a new face to Howdy via the terminal.

Comment: "not functioning properly" is an information-free problem report. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @waltinator notes, "not functioning properly" is not specific enough to provide a solution, nor is Howdy a Ubuntu OS feature. That said, there are known issues over on the Howdy project site on Github. You may want to review those issues here: https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy/issues.